# Clean Architecture - Where does mapping of DTO to business model should happen?

Tags: clean-architecture

I have a DTO that's managed by a Repository and in the end I want to map this DTO to a different type of object that's used by the Presentation layer.

Should the mapping happen in the Repository or in the domain layer? ( Use case/ Interactor)

Comment: What is the domain layer?

Comment: https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html The domain layer is the one named as "Use cases" in the article. It's where the application business logic should be

Answer (score 12):

I think the term DTO is a little too vague to answer this question.  It really depends on what the purpose of the transformation is.

For example, let's assume we have some kind of system that has a Book object in its entities (in the domain layer).  The book object returned by the repositories may have a field named `pendingDelete` because we delete books in a background task in batches.  This field is needed by the domain layer but not externally and so, in the use case layer, we transform the book object into another object (maybe by casting to an interface or maybe creating a whole new object) that does not have this field.  This meets the definition of a DTO in my brain and this mapping would happen in the domain layer.

Alternatively, lets now consider that we need to transform that object into a different object that has been decorated with various annotations/metadata that instruct how to serialize the object into XML or JSON.  This also meets the definition of a DTO but this mapping would happen outside of the domain layer.

In the first example, we are using the DTO to control the interface to our inner layers and so we do that mapping in the inner layers.  In the second example we are using the DTO to control the interface to our outer layers and so we do that mapping in the outer layers.

Comment: > we transform the book object into another object | but which layer does this happen in?

Comment: The second paragraph (where I think your quote is from) talks about mappings that would happen in the domain layer.

Answer (score 11):

In clean architecture the repository returns entities which are "used" by the Interactors to implement the business rules. The Interactors return "response models" (DTOs) which are used by the presenters to generate "view models" which are used by the views to show results to the users.

Depending on the responsibility of ur "different type of object" the mapping would be in the Interactor or presenter.

U can find more details about Interactors and presenters in my blog post here: https://plainionist.github.io/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Controller-Presenter/

Comment: Thank you plainionist for the answer and the blog post. With DTO I mean Entity that comes from an API response. Does this mean that in case of mapping happening in the presenter ,the Presenter would know about this DTO?isn't this bad?

Comment: If you're talking in terms of MVC, it is the Controller's responsibility to transform an Data Model into a Presentation Model

Comment: Does API response mean call of an external service? And do u need the response in ur business logic? Then the repository/gateway would map it to an entity type defined in ur app or enterprise. The Interactors would use it in their business logic and return an Interactor specific response model. The presenter then concerts this into a view model.

Answer (score 0):

**Usecase** makes use of **plugins**. **Plugins** are abstraction over libraries (**Gateway**).

So in this case, a library (native or third party) will have to make an API call and get the json response, then convert it as a DTO object and hand it over to the usecase with the callback method. Then usecase can hand it over to presenter which will then convert it to respective view model.